# Animation clipping image

Tags: jquery

I want to get a animation clipping image effect but I don't know how. This don't work.

```
#img {
    background: url('i1.jpg');
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}   

<a href="#">link</a>
<div id="img"></div>    

$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('img').animate({
            width: '+=300px',
            height: '+=212px'
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PaulP: Try

```
$('#img').animate({
```

You left out the `#`